# Search for substrings of text in a node in a XML file

Tags: php, xpath

I have this PHP I found in a Q&A forum that queries an XML file:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;                                        // Create a new dom document 
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;                              // Set features 
$doc->formatOutput = true;                                     // Create indents on xml 

$doc->Load('i.xml');                                        // Load the file 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 
$query = '//users/user/firstname[.= "'.$_POST["search"].'"]';         // The xpath (starts from root node) 
$names = $xpath->query($query);                                 // A list of matched elements 


$Output=""; 
foreach ($names as  $node) { 
   $Output.=$doc->saveXML($node->parentNode)."\n";             // We get the parent of  "<firstname>" element  (the entire "<user>" node and its children) (maybe get the parent node directly using xpath) 
                                                                // and use the saveXML() to convert it to string   
} 

echo $Output."<br>\n\n";                                      // The result  

echo "<hr><br><b>Below view the results  as HTML content. &nbsp; (See also the page's HTML code):</b>\n<pre>".htmlspecialchars($Output)."</pre>";
```

The script will search the values of all the `firstname` nodes in the XML document from the input from the `POST`, and will return the parent node of the node`firstname`, if the `POST` input value matches any of the node values.

This script works well, but it only returns queries that contain the entire value of a `firstname` node, and will not work if I search for a substring of the node's text (e.g  a query for `Potato` will return `Potato`, but a query for `Pot`, will not give me results for `Potato`).

So how do you get a result that only contains a substring of the node's text, instead of the entire value ?

Comment: maybe try to add wilcard, change:

    $query = '//users/user/firstname[.= "'.$_POST["search"].'"]';


to 


    $query = '//users/user/firstname[.= "'.$_POST["search"].'*"]';

Comment: It will not return any results with wildcard in xpath